# Worklight 7.1 Open native map application with mapkit cordova plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-maps, mapkit

I'm developing a hybrid application using worklight I wants to open the native map (Apple map for iOS and Google Map for Android) with a marker and then back to the application when finished. till now I have implemented open the native map with the url, which open native map on default browser. but my requirement is to open native map on click of markers.

During Google I found Mapkit cordova plugin which solve my problem but i don't how to integrate Mapkit cordova plugin with worklight.
please help me if anyone knows mapkit integration with worklight for android and IOS.

*****************************************************UPDATED:*****************************************

After lot of RnD, i found below plugin: 
[phonegap-launch-navigator](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator) 
. Configuration to install cordova plugin in worklight project is given below

**Code to launch native map**:

> ```
> launchnavigator.navigate(
>           "London, UK",
>           null,
>           function(){
>               alert("Plugin success");
>           },
>           function(error){
>               alert("Plugin error: "+ error);
>           });
> ```

**in Android config.xml:**

> ```
>  <!-- android -->
>   <platform name="android">
>   <js-module src="www/default/js/launchnavigator.js" name="LaunchNavigator">
>    <clobbers target="launchnavigator" />
>    </js-module>
>    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
>   <feature name="LaunchNavigator">
>     <param name="android-package" value="android.LaunchNavigator"/>
>   </feature>
>   </config-file>
>   <source-file src="src/android/LaunchNavigator.java" target-dir="src/com/hhMobileApp" />
>   </platform>
> ```

**java file path**:

> native\src\android\LaunchNavigator.java

**js file path :**

> www\default\js\launchnavigator.js

After config **phonegap-launch-navigator** plugin, getting below error.

> **error**: uncaught referenceError: module is not define.

please suggest your inputs to solve this error to launch native app in android:

Comment: @Idan Adar Can you please look at this issue.

Comment: @Vivin K Can you please look at this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this link: 
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

plugin you can specify in config.xml and then please follow the link.

You can also create your own native mapview and call it using WL.NativePage.show() from javascript.

Comment: thanks for you post. i'll implement and get back to you.

Comment: can you tell me which code i need to copy and paste from plugin.xml to config.xml to run plugin as i m getting "plugin not found" error.